# Python MD5 Hash Passwords and Dictionary

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to create a simple program that collects MD5 Hash passwords and then matches them to a dictionary I've created with common passwords in it.

I can collected the MD5 passwords no problem, the problem is when I try to compare them to a dictionary of words I can't get it working at all.

Any tips or direction would be appreciated, I'm clueless as to what to do next and I've searched for many days online before resorting to asking for assistance.

My code is as follows,

```
import sys, re, hashlib


def dict_attack(passwd_hash):
    print 'dict_attack(): Cracking hash:', passwd_hash
    #set up list of common password words
    passwords = open('J:/dictionary.txt')

    passwd_found = False


    if passwd_found:
        print 'dict_attack(): Password recovered: ' (passwd)
def main():
    print'[dict_crack] Tests'
    passwd_hash = '4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93'
    dict_attack(passwd_hash)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

RELEVANT CODE FOR FURTHER QUESTION

```
 hash_to_crack = password
  dict_file = "J:/dictionary.txt"

with open(dict_file) as fileobj:
    for line in fileobj:
        line = line.strip()
        if hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest() == hash_to_crack:
            print "Successfully cracked the hash %s: It's %s" % (hash_to_crack, line)
            return ""
print "Failed to crack the file."
```

Comment: Can you please show what your file looks like? What's the expected output?

Comment: The contents of the dictionary file are as follows 123,1234 12345, 123456 1234567, 12345678 password, qwerty abc, abcd abc123, 111111 monkey, arsenal letmein, trustno1 dragon, baseball superman, iloveyou starwars, montypython cheese, 123123 football, password batman The expected result is 123123

Comment: Update it in your question please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script does the trick and can work with extremely large files since it doesn't read the whole dictionary at once. Good luck with your code. Comment if you have any problems or questions about this.

```
import hashlib
hash_to_crack = "5badcaf789d3d1d09794d8f021f40f0e"
dict_file = "dict.txt"

def main():
    with open(dict_file) as fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            line = line.strip()
            if hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest() == hash_to_crack:
                print "Successfully cracked the hash %s: It's %s" % (hash_to_crack, line)
                return ""
    print "Failed to crack the file."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**EDIT:** Multiple hash cracking. Enjoy.

```
import hashlib
hashes_to_crack = ["5badcaf789d3d1d09794d8f021f40f0e", "d0763edaa9d9bd2a9516280e9044d885", "8621ffdbc5698829397d97767ac13db3"]
dict_file = "dict.txt"

def main(hash_to_crack):
    with open(dict_file) as fileobj:
        for line in fileobj:
            line = line.strip()
            if hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest() == hash_to_crack:
                print "Successfully cracked the hash %s: It's %s" % (hash_to_crack, line)
                return ""
    print "Failed to crack the file."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for hashToCrack in hashes_to_crack:
        main(hashToCrack)
```

Comment: That works great thanks, do you have any idea how I could edit the code so that it can crack more than one hashes, say I was storing the hashes found under a variable?

Comment: For example in my code i have 'hash_to_crack = password' but it only cracks one hash and not all 3 stored in  password

Comment: Would you like to do it from the command line or by editing the script? @user3057762

Comment: There you go. Enjoy. @user3057762

Answer (score 1):

I'm missing some code in your snippet... maybe this could be a starting point to elaborate (not tested, not sure it works):

```
from hashlib import md5

_hashes = { md5( pwd.strip() ).hexdigest() : pwd.strip()
        for pwd in open('J:/dictionary.txt') }

def main():
    print'[dict_crack] Tests'
    passwd_hash = '4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93'

    if passwd_hash in _hashes:
        print "found %s = %s" % (passwd_hash, _hashes[passwd_hash])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The contents of the dictionary file are as follows             123,1234
12345, 123456
1234567, 12345678
password, qwerty
abc, abcd
abc123, 111111 
monkey, arsenal 
letmein, trustno1  
dragon, baseball  
superman, iloveyou   
starwars, montypython   
cheese, 123123  
football, password   
batman                                                                                                                                  The expected result is 123123

Comment: Thank you for your help but that code is throwing an error at passwd_hash,pwd. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you please give us a detailed hint on your dictionary file? Other than contents, how it is formatted? Generally speaking, a dictionary of common password is just a CR separated file where each line has a password, and I cannot tell that from what you have commented.

Comment: each line in the document is a password yes

Comment: @Guipo, please don't do `passwd_hash  in _hashes.keys()`. Just `passwd_hash in _hashes` is quite sufficient and a lot faster.

Comment: That works great thanks, do you have any idea how I could edit the code so that it can crack more than one hashes, say I was storing the hashes found under a variable?

Comment: For example in my code i have 'passwd_hash = password' but it only cracks one hash and not all 3 stored in password

Comment: @user3057762 can you please add all the specs? Your last comment is a little confusing

Comment: There is a variable passwords with three MD5 hashes stored in it. I want to be able to match all three of these hashes to my dictionary text document but currently it will only match one, the last one. This is the relevant code

Comment: The relevant code is in the original question ive edited it in